# MVC 5 Controller Domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a way of placing a fragment before the controller name in the url, coming from another controller like so:

```
http://site/#Controller/Action.
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragment identifier is not a part of URL but is something that is used in conjunction with it. See [RFC 2396 section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-4.1).

It does not get sent to the server by browsers if you submit a form. Those types of URLs are usually handled by client side JavaScript frameworks like [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route).